# RSA error on WCF Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, encryption, rsa

I have recently encrypted our .NET web config files for our ASPX web applications using RSA encryption.

It works fine for our web applications.

However, its not working in our WCF Services, the calling apps get a server error, looking through the stacktrace I think its related to the RSA key not being able to be opened.

We allowed access to the key on the servers to IIS_IUSRS and NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.

We have a web app, and a WCF service both under the same app pools, the web app seems fine, the WCF service seems to throw an error.

Does anyone know if additional users/app pools need access to the key - specially when running as a WCF service? I have been told individual app pools do not need access and the IIS_IUSERS access should be enough when these components are running in IIS.

Any thoughts/help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to leave WCF web.config unencrypted?

Comment: connectionstring to Server exists in web.config of asp.net and RSA encrypted ? And asp.net connects to WCF and WCF connects to Server? What's the exact architecture?